# Parse JSON using VBA to Loop through all the components of JSON objects and extract label, key, value of each components

Tags: arrays, json, vba, dictionary, parsing

I have a `VBA` code that can `parse` some particular `JSON` files and get the `array("components")` from different depths/layers. Once any components is found, it then extract it's `label` and check if it contains `columns`, `data`, or `values`.

- if columns is found then again check if it contains components
- if data is found then check if it contains values
- if values is found then extract its "label" and "value"

Following code is doing most of it, but some how not perfect. It come up with correct results 90% of the time.

I am in a search of a `loop` that can follow the same pattern but can go deeper as much as it can and extract the "label", "key" and "value" from every component it can find.

Possible path ways are (used JSON editor online to imagine the structure of different JSON):

1. components > components > columns > components > data > values
2. components > components > columns > components > values
3. components > components > data > values
4. components > components > values
5. components > columns > components > data > values
6. components > columns > components > values
7. components > data > values
8. components > values

**In nutshell, for every components found, it will check, if columns exits, or data exist, or values exits.**

if I follow the same structure of the following code then it would be a lot of repeated code so I am in a search of a efficient code that can do all above but in less number of lines. I think that loop will be the answer, but I am not sure how to utilize it in following code.

I have been using JsonConverter to parse JSON file and then using following code:

```
Private Sub Test()
    '==== Change this part according to your implementation..."
    Dim jsontxt As String
    jsontxt = OpenTxtFile("D:/TestJSON2.txt")
    '====

    Dim jSon As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set jSon = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsontxt)
            
    'Check if first level of components exist and get the collection of components if true

    If jSon.Exists("components") Then
        Dim components As Collection
        Set components = jSon("components")
        
        Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        Set DictValue = New Scripting.Dictionary
        
        Dim comFirst As Variant
        Dim comSecond As Variant
        Dim comThird As Variant
        Dim columnsDict As Variant
        Dim valDict As Variant
                    
        For Each comFirst In components
            If Not Dict.Exists(comFirst("label")) Then Dict.Add comFirst("label"), comFirst("key")
            
Columns:
    If comFirst.Exists("columns") Then
        For Each columnsDict In comFirst("columns")
        
            If columnsDict.Exists("components") Then
                For Each comSecond In columnsDict("components")
                
                    If Not Dict.Exists(comSecond("label")) Then Dict.Add comSecond("label"), comSecond("key")
                    If comSecond.Exists("data") Then
                        If comSecond("data").Exists("values") Then
                            For Each valDict In comSecond("data")("values")
                                If Not DictValue.Exists(valDict("label")) Then DictValue.Add valDict("label"), valDict("value")
                            Next valDict
                        End If
                    End If
                    If comSecond.Exists("values") Then
                        For Each valDict In comSecond("values")
                            If Not DictValue.Exists(valDict("label")) Then DictValue.Add valDict("label"), valDict("value")
                        Next valDict
                    End If
                    
                Next
            End If
            
        Next
    End If

Data:
    If comFirst.Exists("data") Then
        If comFirst("data").Exists("values") Then
            For Each valDict In comFirst("data")("values")
                If Not DictValue.Exists(valDict("label")) Then DictValue.Add valDict("label"), valDict("value")
            Next valDict
        End If
    End If

Values:
    If comFirst.Exists("values") Then
        For Each valDict In comFirst("values")
            If Not DictValue.Exists(valDict("label")) Then DictValue.Add valDict("label"), valDict("value")
        Next valDict
    End If

            
            
            
            '++++ New JSON Format ++++
            '==== Check if second level of "components" key exist and extract label-key if true
            If comFirst.Exists("components") Then
            
                For Each comSecond In comFirst("components")
                    If Not Dict.Exists(comSecond("label")) Then Dict.Add comSecond("label"), comSecond("key")
                                    
                    '=== Check if "columns" key exist and extract the key-label if true
                    If comSecond.Exists("columns") Then
                        For Each columnsDict In comSecond("columns")
                        
                            '==== Check if third level of "components" key exist and extract key-label if true
                            If columnsDict.Exists("components") Then
                                For Each comThird In columnsDict("components")
                                    If Not Dict.Exists(comThird("label")) Then Dict.Add comThird("label"), comThird("key")
                                    
                                    If comThird.Exists("data") Then
                                        If comThird("data").Exists("values") Then
                                            For Each valDict In comThird("data")("values")
                                                If Not DictValue.Exists(valDict("label")) Then DictValue.Add valDict("label"), valDict("value")
                                            Next valDict
                                        End If
                                    End If

                                    '==== Check if "values" key exist and extract label-value if true
                                    If comThird.Exists("values") Then
                                        For Each valDict In comThird("values")
                                            If Not DictValue.Exists(valDict("label")) Then DictValue.Add valDict("label"), valDict("value")
                                        Next valDict
                                    End If
                                    '====
                                    
                                Next comThird
                            End If
                            '====
                            
                        Next columnsDict
                    End If
                    '====
                    
                    
    
                    If comSecond.Exists("data") Then
                        If comSecond("data").Exists("values") Then
                            For Each valDict In comSecond("data")("values")
                                If Not DictValue.Exists(valDict("label")) Then DictValue.Add valDict("label"), valDict("value")
                            Next valDict
                        End If
                    End If

                    '==== Check if "values" key exist and extract the label-value if true
                    If comSecond.Exists("values") Then
                        For Each valDict In comSecond("values")
                            If Not DictValue.Exists(valDict("label")) Then DictValue.Add valDict("label"), valDict("value")
                        Next valDict
                    End If
                    '====
                Next comSecond
            End If
            '++++
            
        Next comFirst
    End If
```

**Example for FaneDuru:**

Collection of `components` contain `label` and `key` as follows:

"label":"Ausstelldatum für alle Dokumente lautet", "key":"ausstelldatumFurAlleDokumenteLautet"

So I need to store label and its key in Dictionary as my previous VBA code already doing.

`Dict.Add comFirst("label"), comFirst("key")`

Same goes for collection/Object `Values` in example:

- "label":"Anschreiben",

  "value":"anschreiben"
- "label":"Arbeitsvertrag",

  "value":"arbeitsvertrag"
- "label":"Dienstwagenüberlassungsvertrag",

  "value":"dienstwagenuberlassungsvertrag"
- "label":"Prämie Empfehlung Kollegen",

  "value":"pramieEmpfehlungKollegen"

here I need to store all the `label` and its `value` in Dictionary as my previous VBA code already doing.

`DictValue.Add valDict("label"), valDict("value")`

Comment: It should be good to share "TestJSON2.txt" you tested and **more specifically explain what problem(s) does the above code produces**. 90% does not help at all, in order to localize the problem(s) you try talking about. If one between the shared `json` files is the one your code processes, please, specify which of them it is.

Comment: OK. So, you need to return all found "label"/"key" nodes and their value, for all levels. Is this understanding correct? If so, how would you like them to be returned? If not, what else would you like to be returned and **in which way**?

Comment: We have two dictionaries. We will add components label,key in one dictionary and values label, value in another dictionary. As we are already doing. Please check the code. But problem is it can only dig 3 step down, so I'm searching for a loop that can find every components and get it label and key.

Comment: In the meantime I already prepared an answer returning in Immediate Window. Anyhow, since the dictionary key should all the time be "label", it cannot be loaded more then once. No time to try better understanding your code logic. Please, check the answer II will post and see how a function reading the involved dictionaries should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

1. Firstly create a dictionary `Private` variable on top of the module (in the declarations area):

```
 Private dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

2. Then use the next code. Like I tried explaining in my comment, it analize the collection objects `Type` and acts according to three categories: `Collection Type`, `Dictionary Type` and strings. A recursive `Sub` processes all found dictionaries:

```
Private Sub TestJsonElem()
    Dim jsontxt As String, strFile As String, El, dKey, i As Long, j As Long
    strFile = "C:\Users\Fane Branesti\Downloads\new 12.json"
    jsontxt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strFile, 1).ReadAll
 
    dict.RemoveAll
    Dim jSon As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set jSon = JsonConverter.ParseJSON(jsontxt)
   
    If jSon.Exists("components") Then
        Dim C1 As Collection: Set C1 = jSon("components")
        
        For Each El In C1                                  'iterate between collection elements
            If TypeName(El) = "Dictionary" Then            'in case of a dictionary
                For i = 0 To El.count - 1                  'iterate between the dictionary items/keys
                    Select Case TypeName(El.Items()(i))    'act according to dictionary item type:
                         Case "Dictionary"                 'if a dictionary:
                                processDict El.Items()(i)  'send it to the recursive Sub extracting labels
                         Case "Collection"                 'iterate between coll elements and send the dictionaries
                                                           'to recursive Sub
                                For j = 1 To El.Items()(i).count
                                    processDict El.Items()(i)(j) 'send each dictionary to recursive Sub
                                Next j
                         Case Else                               'if no object (String, Boolean, Null):
                                If El.Keys()(i) = "label" Then   'and it is "label"
                                   'place the dictionary "label" as key and dictiorary "key" as value
                                    If Not dict.Exists(El("label")) Then _
                                          dict(El("label")) = IIf(El("key") = "", "Empty", El("key"))
                                End If
                     End Select
                Next i
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'return the dictionary keys/items:
    For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        Debug.Print dict.Keys()(i) & " : " & dict.Items()(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Sub processDict(ByVal d As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 0 To d.count - 1                                   'iterate between the dictionary items/keys
            If TypeName(d.Items()(i)) = "Collection" Then      'in case of a collection iterate between its dictionaries
                For j = 1 To d.Items()(i).count
                    processDict d.Items()(i)(j)                'call the Sub itself recursively
                Next j
            ElseIf TypeName(d.Items()(i)) = "Dictionary" Then
                processDict d.Items()(i)                       'call the Sub itself recursively
            Else
                 If d.Keys()(i) = "label" Then
                         'place the dictionary "label" as key and dictiorary "key" as value
                         If Not dict.Exists((d("label"))) Then _
                                  dict(d("label")) = IIf(d("key") = "", "Empty", d("key"))
                End If
            End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

But you must know that there are multiple occurrences for some dictionary keys and the code (as yours has been  built and taken as model) returns **only the first one**, according to the iteration order. I can adapt the code to returns all of them (exept existing, if the case). I mean for the same key the dictionary value will contain all "key" values separated by, let us say "|", or some other character. Or make it to return the last occurrence and the code will be faster not preliminary checking if the key exists.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the quick response, code is working. but as already described in question that I need label text added to another dictionary with its key. by using `If Not Dict.Exists("label") Then Dict.Add "label", "key"` can you guide me how I can extract both?

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq Do you want adding the same dictionary key ("label") more than once? If so, as I tried stating in my comment,  this is not possible! `Scripting.Dictinary` does not allow that. It is frequently used to extract unique keys from a range containing duplicates. If you want something different, please specify what you really want. If you really want dealing with a dictionary and my above mentioned understanding is correct, I can do that **only using an incremented variable** and build unique keys by concatenating "Label" with the variable in discussion. Resulting "lb1", "lb2", "lb3" etc

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq But **how do you intend to use the resulted dictionary**? I will maybe place only the ('label') values in an array, "label" being identic for all of them. This is connected to what you want accomplishing. Do you **only** want playing with a `Dictionary`? Is this a theme from somebody else, or what?

Comment: For each `"components"` I need to store "label"  with its "key" into another Dict . i.e `Dict.Add gruppeI, Gruppe I` 
So that I can use both values when ever I need it. 
However if its already in dictionary then we don't need to store it. same goes for `values`, I need to add its label, value i.e `Dict.Add  label, value`

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq 1. If we will communicate ones per day, I'm afraid, we will not solve anything, even if I try helping. But, in order to help, I need **to understand** what you want. It also may be a language problem, but this is besides the issue. I am not a native English speaker, too. 2. Please take from the file the above code processes **some elocvent examples** for what you need. I started understanding/supposing that you do not need/want the label "label" and its value (separated by ":"), but I still cannot understand what you want. I am afraid, without an example It will be more difficult.

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq If you will not be able to give me a sign in the next hour, I'm also afraid that I will abandon this project. It is, at least strange, that **me to be more interested in solving it then you**, no offence... It takes maximum two minutes to check what is it about.

Comment: Sorry to bother you/ and for late reply. but the approach that you choose can only result labels. its actually looping through all the elements one by one therefore cannot add both label, key into dictionary at the same time.

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq Your comment does not clarify anything! **Can you supply the example, as I required above**? I will maybe understand what you need. And a dictionary has a `Key` property and a `Item` property, too. The key must be unique, but the item can be anything (string, number, array, object...).

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq If you will supply an elocvent example, or more, please edit your question and place the supplementary information there. Then, only announce me in a comment about it...

Comment: Your loop approach is good but I think you need to use `for each collection` instead of `for i to count`. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq I am very busy now... I will try something else in the evening, when I will be at home. Only now I understood the meaning of the "label" and "key".  I thought that the string "label" as it is must be returned and 'its value/key' should be what it follows after ":" character. That's why the same "label" string could not be accepted by a dictionary... Now, I can see that what follows after "label:" should be returned as dictionary key and what follows after "key:", as dictionary item. The iteration logic has to be changed. But I cannot do it now.

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq Please, test the updated code and send some feedback. It will return what (I understood.) you need...

Comment: your approach is really great. doing exactly what I require, However the `components` may contains some **"values"** `arrays` which will have `value` instead of `key` so there are several values. also `components` may contain `data` object and then `values` array. I have already discussed the possible pathways of values in my question. I appreciate your time. I have change the code `Dict(El("label")) = IIf(El("key") = "", El("value"), El("key"))`

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq This is what I wanted to suggest and I already was testing. But I was trying to see if there are situations when `El("label")` exists but neither "value" or "key" exist. Is it possible that such a situation exist? Not any error will be raised for such a case,  but I was thinking that I maybe will find a way to make it return elegantly...:)

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq But is it anything from your question which the above code did not answer? If so, please mention it. If not, we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, thick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the suggested solution works. Very rarely people look in comments, too...